# FileReader events not firing in Meteor Cordova project using cordova-plugin-file in android app

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, filereader, cordova-plugin-file

The filereaeder events like onloadend are not being fired in my android app build with meteor 1.4 using the cordova-plugin-file plugin.

```
        resolveLocalFileSystemURL(pathToFile, function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function(event) {
                    // this event does not fire
                    console.log(event.target.result);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            },function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

This issue seems to be linked to [Can't read a file from android directory using cordova-plugin-file plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303863/cant-read-a-file-from-android-directory-using-cordova-plugin-file-plugin)

I tried to install an older version of the file plugin like they suggest in that question

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-file@3.0.0
```

However when I run my application it automatically installs a newer version of the plugin

```
WARNING: Attempting to install plugin cordova-plugin-file@3.0.0, but it should have a minimum version of 4.1.1 to ensure compatibility with the current platform versions. Installing the minimum version for convenience, but you should adjust your
         dependencies.
```

Could it be that the Cordova build packaged with meteor 1.4 doesn't support the most recent version of the cordova-plugin-file. Can I somehow downgrade it or force meteor to install the older plugin version?

Comment: Do you have any error in console.

Comment: No erros in console, reader.onloadend just doesn't fire. And i'm certain I got to the File method of fileEntry because I can log a message there.

`fileEntry.file(function(file) {
     console.log('this is shown in console')`

Comment: Had you confirmed the path of file ?

Comment: Yes, when I do console.log(JSON.stringify(file, null, 4)); I get this result, so i know the path works and that the file is there:

` fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(file, null, 4));`

`{
    "name": "camerapreview_03_08_2016_1257_54_preview.jpg",
    "localURL": "cdvfile://localhost/files/camerapreview_03_08_2016_1257_54_preview.jpg",
    "type": "image/jpeg",
    "lastModified": 1470221874000,
    "lastModifiedDate": 1470221874000,
    "size": 14487,
    "start": 0,
    "end": 14487
} `

Comment: Is there a fix for this?